# Count occurrences and stretch array in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, find-occurrences

Let

```
input = [0 0 0 5 5 7 8 8];
```

I now want to transform this vector into the form

```
output = [3 3 3 3 5 5 6 8];
```

Which basically is a stairs plot.

**Explanation**

The input vector is used to plot data points along the x-axis. The y-axis is thereby provided by 1:length(input). So the resulting plot shows the cumulative number of datapoints along the y-axis and the time of occurrence along the x-axis.

I now want to fit a model against my dataset. Therefor I need a vector that provides the correct value for a certain time (x-value).

The desired output vector basically is the result of a stairs plot. I am looking for an efficient way to generate the desired vector in matlab. The result of

```
[x, y] = stairs(input, 1:length(input));
```

did not bring me any closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with [`bsfxun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
x = [0 0 0 5 5 7 8 8];
y = sum(bsxfun(@le, x(:), min(x):max(x)), 1);
```

This counts, for each element in `1:numel(x)`, how many elements of `x` are less than or equal to that.

Comment: Replacing 1:numel(x) with 1:max(x) did the job! Thank you very much. Very nice solution!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Shouldn't it then be `y = sum(bsxfun(@le, x(:), min(x):max(x)), 1)`? (considering `x = [2 2 2 5 5 7 8]` for example)

Comment: You are correct. In case min(x) is different from 1 the result would have leading zeros. Thanks again!